# TCP Server with bi-directional communication

Tags: c#, winforms, sockets, tcp, tcplistener

I have attempted to create a TCP service that is able to achieve what I wish but sadly I am getting stuck at the last hurdle.

The Scenario:
A single server instance is running with 10 clients all connected, a client will send a command, and receive the response.  This is all working fine.  However the last scenario isn't working

When a client issues an "UPDATE" command, the server should then send a message back to all connected clients that they need to do something.

---

**Example Comms:**

```
1
Client A          GetTime ----->          Server
Client A          <----- Time is...       Server 

2
Client A          UPDATE ------>          Server
Client A          <------- Ack            Server
Client A          <------- DoUpdate       Server
Client B          <------- DoUpdate       Server
Client C          <------- DoUpdate       Server
```

Comms 1 abover works, mainly because of the call to send and call to reeive, but for comms 2 I cannot workout how I can achieve this, at least not without opening a second port for the communication which isn't ideal.

---

**Current attempt based on Microsoft Article**

Server

```
class Program
{
    public static int Main(String[] args)
    {
        AsynchronousSocketListener.StartListening();
        return 0;
    }
}
public class StateObject
{
    // Client  socket.
    public Socket WorkSocket = null;
    // Size of receive buffer.
    public const int BufferSize = 1024;
    // Receive buffer.
    public byte[] Buffer = new byte[BufferSize];
    // Received data string.
    public StringBuilder Sb = new StringBuilder();
}

public class AsynchronousSocketListener
{
    // Thread signal.
    public static ManualResetEvent AllDone = new ManualResetEvent(false);

    public static void StartListening()
    {
        // Data buffer for incoming data.
        //var bytes = new Byte[1024];

        // Establish the local endpoint for the socket.
        // The DNS name of the computer
        // running the listener is "host.contoso.com".
    //??IPHostEntry ipHostInfo = Dns.Resolve(Dns.GetHostName());
    //??IPAddress ipAddress = ipHostInfo.AddressList[0];
    //??IPEndPoint localEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, 3030);

    // Create a TCP/IP socket.
    var listener = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

    // Bind the socket to the local endpoint and listen for incoming connections.
    try
    {
        listener.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 3030));
        //listener.Bind(localEndPoint);
        listener.Listen(100);

        while (true)
        {
            // Set the event to nonsignaled state.
            AllDone.Reset();

            // Start an asynchronous socket to listen for connections.
            Console.WriteLine("Waiting for a connection...");
            listener.BeginAccept((AcceptCallback), listener);

            // Wait until a connection is made before continuing.
            AllDone.WaitOne();
        }

    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
    }

    Console.WriteLine("\nPress ENTER to continue...");
    Console.Read();

}

public static void AcceptCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
{
    // Signal the main thread to continue.
    AllDone.Set();

    // Get the socket that handles the client request.
    var listener = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;
    Socket handler = listener.EndAccept(ar);

    // Create the state object.
    var state = new StateObject {WorkSocket = handler};
    handler.BeginReceive(state.Buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, 0, ReadCallback, state);
}

public static void ReadCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
{
    // Retrieve the state object and the handler socket
    // from the asynchronous state object.
    var state = (StateObject)ar.AsyncState;
    Socket handler = state.WorkSocket;

    // Read data from the client socket. 
    int bytesRead = handler.EndReceive(ar);

    if (bytesRead > 0)
    {
        // There  might be more data, so store the data received so far.
        state.Sb.Append(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(
            state.Buffer, 0, bytesRead));

        // Check for end-of-file tag. If it is not there, read 
        // more data.
        var content = state.Sb.ToString();
        if (content.IndexOf("<EOF>", StringComparison.Ordinal) > -1)
        {
            // All the data has been read from the 
            // client. Display it on the console.
            Console.WriteLine("Read {0} bytes from socket. \n Data : {1}",
                content.Length, content);
            // Echo the data back to the client.
            Send(handler, content);
        }
        else
        {
            // Not all data received. Get more.
            handler.BeginReceive(state.Buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, 0, ReadCallback, state);
        }
    }
}

private static void Send(Socket handler, String data)
{
    // Convert the string data to byte data using ASCII encoding.
    var byteData = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);

    // Begin sending the data to the remote device.
    handler.BeginSend(byteData, 0, byteData.Length, 0, SendCallback, handler);
}

private static void SendCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
{
    try
    {
        // Retrieve the socket from the state object.
        var handler = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;

        // Complete sending the data to the remote device.
        int bytesSent = handler.EndSend(ar);
        Console.WriteLine("Sent {0} bytes to client.", bytesSent);

        handler.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
        handler.Close();

    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
    }
}

/*
public static int Main(String[] args)
{
    StartListening();
    return 0;
}
 * */
}
```

Client Code

```
class Program
{
    public static int Main(String[] args)
    //static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.Title = "Client ";
        AsynchronousClient.StartClient();
        Console.ReadLine();
        return 0;
    }
}

public class StateObject
{
// Client socket.
public Socket WorkSocket = null;
// Size of receive buffer.
public const int BufferSize = 256;
// Receive buffer.
public byte[] Buffer = new byte[BufferSize];
// Received data string.
public StringBuilder Sb = new StringBuilder();
}

public class AsynchronousClient
{
// The port number for the remote device.
private const int Port = 3030;

// ManualResetEvent instances signal completion.
private static readonly ManualResetEvent ConnectDone =
    new ManualResetEvent(false);
private static readonly ManualResetEvent SendDone =
    new ManualResetEvent(false);
private static readonly ManualResetEvent ReceiveDone =
    new ManualResetEvent(false);

// The response from the remote device.
private static String _response = String.Empty;

public static void StartClient()
{
    // Connect to a remote device.
    try
    {
        // Establish the remote endpoint for the socket.
        // The name of the 
        // remote device is "host.contoso.com".
        //IPHostEntry ipHostInfo = Dns.Resolve("host.contoso.com");
        //??IPHostEntry ipHostInfo = Dns.Resolve("localhost");
        //??IPAddress ipAddress = ipHostInfo.AddressList[0];
        //??IPEndPoint remoteEP = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, port);

        // Create a TCP/IP socket.
        var client = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

        // Connect to the remote endpoint.

        //client.BeginConnect(remoteEP,
            //new AsyncCallback(ConnectCallback), client);
        var remoteEP = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), Port);
        client.BeginConnect(remoteEP, ConnectCallback, client);
        ConnectDone.WaitOne();

        // set receive to another thread so we can constantly receive, doesn't work as intended
        //var thread = new Thread(() => ReadThread(client));
        //thread.Start();

        // Send test data to the remote device.
        Send(client, "This is a test<EOF>");
        SendDone.WaitOne();

        //test remove
        // Receive the response from the remote device.
        Receive(client);
        ReceiveDone.WaitOne();

        // Write the response to the console.
        Console.WriteLine("Response received : {0}", _response);

        // Release the socket.
        //client.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
        //client.Close();

    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
    }
}

// doesn't work as expected
private static void ReadThread(object ar)
{
    var client = (Socket)ar;
    while (true)
    {
        Receive(client);
        ReceiveDone.WaitOne();

        // Write the response to the console.
        Console.WriteLine("Response received : {0}", _response);
    }
}

private static void ConnectCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
{
    try
    {
        // Retrieve the socket from the state object.
        var client = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;

        // Complete the connection.
        client.EndConnect(ar);

        Console.WriteLine("Socket connected to {0}", client.RemoteEndPoint);

        // Signal that the connection has been made.
        ConnectDone.Set();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
    }
}

private static void Receive(Socket client)
{
    try
    {
        // Create the state object.
        var state = new StateObject {WorkSocket = client};

        // Begin receiving the data from the remote device.
        client.BeginReceive(state.Buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, 0, ReceiveCallback, state);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
    }
}

private static void ReceiveCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
{
    try
    {
        // Retrieve the state object and the client socket 
        // from the asynchronous state object.
        var state = (StateObject)ar.AsyncState;
        Socket client = state.WorkSocket;

        // Read data from the remote device.
        int bytesRead = client.EndReceive(ar);

        if (bytesRead > 0)
        {
            // There might be more data, so store the data received so far.
            state.Sb.Append(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(state.Buffer, 0, bytesRead));

            // Get the rest of the data.
            client.BeginReceive(state.Buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, 0, ReceiveCallback, state);
        }
        else
        {
            // All the data has arrived; put it in response.
            if (state.Sb.Length > 1)
            {
                _response = state.Sb.ToString();
            }
            // Signal that all bytes have been received.
            ReceiveDone.Set();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
    }
}

private static void Send(Socket client, String data)
{
    // Convert the string data to byte data using ASCII encoding.
    var byteData = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);

    // Begin sending the data to the remote device.
    client.BeginSend(byteData, 0, byteData.Length, 0, SendCallback, client);
}

private static void SendCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
{
    try
    {
        // Retrieve the socket from the state object.
        var client = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;

        // Complete sending the data to the remote device.
        int bytesSent = client.EndSend(ar);
        Console.WriteLine("Sent {0} bytes to server.", bytesSent);

        // Signal that all bytes have been sent.
        SendDone.Set();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
    }
}

/*
public static int Main(String[] args)
{
    StartClient();
    return 0;
}
*/
}
```

---

**Previous system that worked**

Server:

```
class Program
{

    private static byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    public static Socket _serverSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
    public static List<Socket> clientSockets = new List<Socket>();

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.Title = "Server, " + clientSockets.Count + " clients are connected";
        SetupServer();
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
    public static void SetupServer()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Setting up server...");
        _serverSocket.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 3030));
        _serverSocket.Listen(10);
        _serverSocket.BeginAccept(AcceptCallback, null);
        Console.ReadLine();// stops cmd from closing
    }

    public static void AcceptCallback(IAsyncResult AR)
    {
        Socket socket = _serverSocket.EndAccept(AR);
        if (!clientSockets.Contains(socket))
            clientSockets.Add(socket);
        IPEndPoint remoteIPEndPoint = socket.RemoteEndPoint as IPEndPoint;

        Console.WriteLine(remoteIPEndPoint.Address);

        Console.WriteLine("Client Connected");
        Console.Title = "Server, " + clientSockets.Count + " clients are connected";
        socket.BeginReceive(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, RecieveCallBack, socket);
        _serverSocket.BeginAccept(AcceptCallback, null);
    }

    private static void RecieveCallBack(IAsyncResult AR)
    {
        var socket = (Socket)AR.AsyncState;
        int received = socket.EndReceive(AR);
        var databuff = new byte[received];
        Array.Copy(buffer, databuff, received);

        string s = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(databuff);
        Console.WriteLine("Text Received: " + s);
        string response = string.Empty;

        switch (s.ToLower())
        {
            case "get time":
                response = DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString();
                break;
            case "hello":
                response = "olleh";
                break;
            case "update clients":
                response = "";
                SendData("Ack", socket);
                doUpdateClients();
                break;
            default:
                response = "Invavlid Request";
                break;
        }

        SendData(response, socket);
    }

    private static void SendData(string Data, Socket socket)
    {
        byte[] data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Data);
        socket.BeginSend(data, 0, data.Length, SocketFlags.None, sendCallback, socket);
        socket.BeginReceive(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, RecieveCallBack, socket);
    }

    private static void doUpdateClients()
    {
        // need to send an update message to all the clients
        var upd = new Thread((UpdateClients));
        upd.Start();
    }

    private static void UpdateClients()
    {
        Thread.Sleep(5000);
        foreach (var sock in clientSockets)
        {
            SendData("UpdateClients", sock);
        }
    }
    private static void sendCallback(IAsyncResult AR)
    {
        var socket = (Socket)AR.AsyncState;
        socket.EndSend(AR);
    }
    //
}

}
```

Client:

```
class Program
{

    private static byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    public static Socket _clientSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.Title = "Client ";
        LoopConnect();
        //ReceiveLoopStart();
        //_clientSocket.Listen(10);
        SendLoop();
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static void LoopConnect()
    {
        while (!_clientSocket.Connected)
        {
            try
            {
                _clientSocket.Connect(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), 3030);
            }
            catch (SocketException se)
            {

            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Connected");
    }
    private static void ReceiveLoopStart()
    {
        //_clientSocket.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 3030));
        //_clientSocket.Listen(10);
        _clientSocket.BeginAccept(AcceptCallback, null);

        Thread receiveThread = new Thread(ReceiveLoop);
        receiveThread.Start();
    }

    private static void ReceiveLoop()
    {
        _clientSocket.BeginReceive(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, RecieveCallBack, _clientSocket);
        _clientSocket.BeginAccept(AcceptCallback, null);
    }

    private static void RecieveCallBack(IAsyncResult AR)
    {
        int received = _clientSocket.EndReceive(AR);
        var databuff = new byte[received];
        Array.Copy(buffer, databuff, received);

        string s = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(databuff);
        Console.WriteLine("Text Received: " + s);
        string response = string.Empty;

        switch (s.ToLower())
        {
            case "get time":
                response = DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString();
                break;
            case "hello":
                response = "olleh";
                break;
            default:
                response = "Invavlid Request";
                break;
        }

    }
    public static void AcceptCallback(IAsyncResult AR)
    {
        Socket socket = _clientSocket.EndAccept(AR);

        Console.WriteLine("Client Connected");
        socket.BeginReceive(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, RecieveCallBack, socket);
        _clientSocket.BeginAccept(AcceptCallback, null);
    }



    private static void SendLoop()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            Console.Write("Enter Request: ");
            string req = Console.ReadLine();

            var buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(req);
            _clientSocket.Send(buffer);

            var tempBuff = new byte[1024];
            int rec = _clientSocket.Receive(tempBuff);

            var data = new byte[rec];
            Array.Copy(tempBuff, data, rec);

            Console.WriteLine("Received: " + Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data));
        }
    }


}
}
```

Comment: Your design is wrong to do this. It is ok if each thread runs in isolation but if one thread receives something, you want to reply from the other threads as well, but they are stuck in their read operation. The only way out is to change  the design and use select with only a single thread that handles all connections.

Comment: Don't you need a listener thread on the client, your are sending updates from server, but i cant see that your client is listening. The client is only listens when it sends something.

Comment: I have attempted several methods of server and client code, I didn't want to post them all as it may cause confusion, but I'll post the attempted code for each one.

Comment: @PhilipStuyck 
I have added the old code I wrote that fully works, when multiple clients are connected it works for get time, but when one does an update clients all clients have to do a send before they get the updateclient message back, when what I need is more like a push notification system

Comment: @Neo your design is wrong, because all threads are stuck in a blocking read. It is as simple as that. You need to process all clients in the same thread and use select.

Comment: @PhilipStuyck I hear what you are saying however I am unsure on how to achieve this.

Comment: The design would be completely different so you must first look for examples that make use of select, and try and understand that code. Google on select and you can get started by that. Myself I learned in C, C++ by using 'UNIX network programming the sockets networking api' http://www.amazon.com/Unix-Network-Programming-Volume-Networking/dp/0131411551

Comment: The select pattern is obsolete when it comes to sockets and .NET. The best way to do socket code is to use synchronous IO and threads. That's the easiest way. If you can't do that (or don't want to) use await. never use anything else when you are on >=C#5. This code is a steaming mess. I suggest that you drop everything that is based on MSDN samples and rewrite it.

Comment: @usr usually each connection does not influence the other connections. If that were the case you would not need select. Btw threads are obsolete too because there is async and await. (ref Steven's cleary's book Concurrency in C# Cookbook)

Comment: Threads are not at all obsolete. They win when it comes to simplicity and productivity. Being able to pause the debugger and see what the app is doing is valuable. Async IO is for GUI apps, concurrency and saving memory in large amounts.

Comment: @PhilipStuyck I'm kind of confused, you said I would need to overhaul the design of the code for it to work how I wanted it, yet I have it working as expected, is there any issues that may arrise from the code located http://pastebin.com/SnFR09Sq for the client code

Comment: The readthread is a busy wait. You really need some kind of blocking call, which is what select is all about. It only wakes up if there is something to do for any of the sockets otherwise it remains asleep... I know this is not that easy. Doing this correctly is easier said than done.

Comment: Just because one thread is stuck in a blocking read on a socket, it does not mean that another thread cannot write to that socket.  Using an select/epoll asynch design is not the only way to do this.

Answer (score 3):

I don't have an example up my sleeve here in C# but what you need to learn is to use the select api.
You only need a single thread to do this. You use the same thread to process all sockets that are in use at any point in time.
If nobody is connected you only have the listening socket. And you then only use the select api to watch what happens on that socket. Select is a blocking call when no timeout is specified. If data is available, then that means that you can call accept. The result of accept is as you know another socket. You now use 2 sockets in select. Again select will block until one of those sockets has data. Perhaps the listening socket again, so you get another socket after calling accept. You now use 3 sockets in select. Suppose now one of the accept sockets have data available you will see that by the using the select api properly. And you can then use any of those sockets to send something over it, except of course the listening socket that is not intended for sending.

More info can be found here :
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20066/A-scalable-client-server-using-select-socket-funct

It uses what I explained and gives more elaborate explanations too.

Comment: Thanks for this, spent a while googling but couldn't find much with what I was searching for

Answer (score 1):

I'm not getting in to your design , but it seems like you can't even reference the other clients.
why don't you save a collection of sockets like so :

```
 private List<Socket> _handlers = new List<Socket>();
 public static void AcceptCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
 {   
     Socket handler = listener.EndAccept(ar);    
     var state = new StateObject {WorkSocket = handler};
     handlers.Add(handler);
     handler.BeginReceive(state.Buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, 0,   ReadCallback, state);
 }
```

And then on receive according to the message type or whatever you should notify these clients.( all of them not just the one currently passed to the ReciveCallback.

```
 public static void ReadCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
 {
      if("<EOF>")
      {
         foreach(var h in _handlers)
         {
             Send(h,data);
         } 
      } 
 }
```

Comment: please check the additional code that was added under "Previous system that worked"

Comment: that's allot of code. and i just saw that . well your previous system can indeed work.. how else are you going to signal them . unless of course setting a timeout on BeginReceive and letting the loop iterate again foreach client. a kind of pooling mechanism.